# Registration form function overlaps with search form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have been having problems with my forms in php, i have a search form and a register form, but whenever i include the header.php where the search form is in the same page as the register form, the register form requires that the search textbox should also be filled out....please help...thanks in advance... Here is where search form is:

```
<?php //header.php

echo "<header class='top' role='header'>
     <div class='container head' style='padding:0 !important;'>
        <nav class='navbar navbar-default' style='margin-bottom:0px;'>
            <div class='container-fluid' style='background-color:white;'>

                <div class='navbar-header'>
                    <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle collapsed'           data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1' aria-expanded='false'>
                        <span class='sr-only'>
                            Toggle navigation
                        </span>
                        <span class='icon-bar'>
                        </span>
                        <span class='icon-bar'>
                        </span>
                        <span class='icon-bar'>
                        </span>
                    </button>

                    <a class='navbar-brand' href=''>
                        <img id='logo' class='logo' name='logo' src='../images/euLogo.png' />
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1'>                        
                    <form class='navbar-form navbar-left frm-search' role='search'>
                        <div class='form-group'>
                            <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Search' />
                        </div>

                        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-info'>
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'>
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </form>

                    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
                        <li>
                            <a href=''><img id='btn-credits' class='btn-credits' name='btn-credits' src='../images/piggybank.png' />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href='https://www.facebook.com/uniteenglish/?fref=ts'>
                                <img id='btn-FBLike' name='btn-FBLike' class='btn-FBLike' src='../images/like.png' />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='dropdown'>
                            <a href='' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>
                                Welcome 
                                <label id='user-name' name='user-name' class='user-name'> 
                                </label> 
                                <span class='caret'>
                                </span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>
                                        My Account
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>
                                        My Credits
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>
                                        Something else here
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li role='separator' class='divider'>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>
                                        Separated link
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>";
?>
```

And the register.php:

```
<?php 
echo "<div class='container'>

<br/>

    <form action='registeruser.php' id='frm-register' name='frm-register' class='frm-register' method='POST'>

        <label>

            User name: 

        </label> 

        <input type='text' id='username' class='form-control frm' name='username' />

        <span class='errorMessage'>

        </span>

        <br/>

        <label>

            Email: 

        </label> 

        <input type='email' id='email' class='form-control frm' name='email' />

        <span class='errorMessage'>

        </span>

        <br/>

        <label>

            Confirm Email: 

        </label> 

        <input type='email' id='re_email' class='form-control frm' name='re_email' />

        <span class='errorMessage'>

        </span>

        <br/>

        <label>

            Password: 

        </label> 

        <input type='password' id='password' class='form-control frm' name='password' />

        <span class='errorMessage'>

        </span>

        <br/>

        <label>

            Confirm Password: 

        </label> 

        <input type='password' id='re_password' class='form-control frm' name='re_password' />

        <span class='errorMessage'>

        </span>

        <br/>

        <label>

            I am a: 

        </label> 

        <select id='iam' class='form-control frm' name='iam'>

            <option value='Teacher'>

                Teacher

            </option>

            <option value='Student'>

                Student

            </option>

            <option value='Parent'>

                Parent

            </option>

        </select>

        <br/>

        <label> 

            <input type='checkbox' id='agree' name='agree' class='check' value='I agree to terms and conditions and privacy policy.' /> 

            I agree to terms and conditions and privacy policy.

        </label>

        <br/>

        <br/>

        <label>

            Registration Type: 

        </label> 

        <input type='text' id='role' class='form-control frm' name='role' value='Member' readonly />

        <br/>

        <input type='submit' id='btn-register' class='form-control btn btn-danger frm' name='btn-register' value='Register Now' />

        <br/>

        <br/>

    </form>

</div>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are not assigning the minimun attributes for the search form and the register is making it required. Should be fixed like this:

```
<form class='navbar-form navbar-left frm-search' role='search' name='search' method="post" action="yourfile.php">
  <div class='form-group'>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Search' />
  </div>
  <button type='submit' class='btn btn-info'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>
  </button>
</form>
```

This is a problem about identification, because the register form thinks that the search belongs to it.

For further information and good practices I recommend you [this post](https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/working-bootstrap-contact-form/).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @ryzen1226 No problem, if this answers was valid mark it so other people with the same problem can find it :)